# How to get pycharm to output colours when running pytest?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

When I run pytest from terminal, I will get colours for the output, but when I run pytest from pycharm (which outputs to the Run toolbar), it is coloured the same as the rest of the stdout.

Is there any way of getting colours out of pytest when run through pycharm?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set `--color=yes` to force colored output. Either in your `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
addopts=--color=yes
```

Or in PyCharm, in run configuration add `--color=yes` in the "Additional Arguments" field:

[image]